# Cannot send Django email

Tags: python, django, email

I am trying to send email notification when user will receive a message in my application from another user. But for some reason emails are not sending. Email accounts are configured properly on a server.

I do not have any errors. Django version 1.10.6.

**settings.py**:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'my.smtp.host'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemailaccount@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

class View(TemplateView):
    def post(self, request, pk):
        form = MessagesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            message = form.save(commit=False)
            message.sender = request.user
            message.reciever = User.objects.get(pk=pk)

            reciever_id = User.objects.get(pk=pk).pk

            message.save()

            email = EmailMessage('Hello', 'World', to=[message.reciever.email])

            if message.reciever.userprofile.email_notifications:
                print('message should be send')
                email.send()

            form = MessagesForm()
            return redirect(reverse('user_messages:user_messages', args=[reciever_id],))

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

**server-log**:

```
message should be send
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Hello
From: mail@from
To: mail@to
Date: Tue, 13 Jun 2017 20:09:49 -0000
Message-ID: <something....>

World
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Make sure this is True `message.reciever.userprofile.email_notifications` secondly check your spam folder.

Comment: @HusainBasrawala First thing you mentioned is for sure True. Spam is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#console-backend):

> Instead of sending out real emails the console backend just writes the
>   emails that would be sent to the standard output. By default, the
>   console backend writes to stdout. You can use a different stream-like
>   object by providing the stream keyword argument when constructing the
>   connection.

Use:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```